# Not able to connect to postgres database from docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to use docker-compose to use Postgres database with my application build in nodejs. I build the code and using it with docker-compose as shown in the file. Then to connect with database I used DB_HOST environment variable.
I am using following code for docker-compse.yml file

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: type

  server:
    image: hardik/type:1.0.0
    ports:
      - '3001:4000'
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
```

But it is unable to connect to the database and gives error saying 'connection refused'

Answer (score 0):

Here below is a docker-compose file for setup node application with postgres database.

```
 networks:
  main:
 volumes:
  db-postgres:
 services:
  app:
   container_name: app
   image: node:latest
   restart: always
   volumes:
     - ./app:/home/node/app
   working_dir: /home/node/app
   ports:
    - 3000:3000
   networks:
    - main
   command: "npm start"
   depends_on:
    - db

   db:
    container_name: db
    image: postgres:latest-pg11
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER= 'xyz'
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD='pwd0123456789'
      - POSTGRES_DB= 'testdb'
    networks:
      - main
    volumes:
      - db-postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

Comment: I have figured out the error usig this file but now I am getting this error 'UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The server does not support SSL connections'

Comment: can you share your Postgres connection string or connection object?

Comment: ```{
    "name": "production",
    "type": "postgres",
    "url": "postgres://postgres:postgres@db:5432/type?ssl=true",
    "synchronize": true,
    "logging": true,
    "ssl": true
  }```